# PHP preg_match displaying Array ( )

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I'm newbie in PHP and I'm trying to scrape just weather summary data from a forecast site, i tried everything i found but it only returns Array ( )

```
<?php

$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Podgorica/forecasts/latest");

preg_match('/ <a class="forecast-magellan-target" name="forecast-part-0"><div data-magellan-destination="forecast-part-0"><\/div><\/a><p class="summary"> (.*?)  <\/span><\/p> /is',$contents, $matches);

print_r($matches);



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have extra spaces, please try this:

```
preg_match('/<a class="forecast-magellan-target" name="forecast-part-0"><div data-magellan-destination="forecast-part-0"><\/div><\/a><p class="summary">(.*?)<\/span><\/p>/is',$contents, $matches);
```